# TCPClient - Send & Receive Response

Tags: java, c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I'm connecting to a remote TCP Listener that receives a string, and responds with a response.

Going from my Windows 8 Phone App, to a Java Jar. The Jar **IS** receiving the message, but the Windows 8 Phone App is not getting the response.

C# Code

```
outputClient.Connect (/IP ADDRESS/, /Port/);

        using (Socket sock = outputClient.Client) {
            sock.Send (UTF8Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (broadcastMessage));

            var response = new byte[100];

            sock.Receive (response);
            var str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString (response).Replace ("\0", "");
            Console.WriteLine ("[RECV] {0}", str);
        } <-- JAVA CODE DOESN'T GET HIT UNTIL THIS LINE IS COMPLETED
```

Java Code

```
String clientSentence;
        ServerSocket socketServer = new ServerSocket(/* PORT */);

        while (true)
        {
            Socket connectionSocket = socketServer.accept();
            connectionSocket.setKeepAlive(true);

            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();

            BufferedWriter outToClient = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream()));

            if (clientSentence != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    JsonObject json = new JsonParser().parse(clientSentence).getAsJsonObject();
                    String un = json.get("Username").toString();
                    String uuid = "2c9c79a096ef4d869fb1d1e07469bb41".replaceAll(                                            
                            "(\\w{8})(\\w{4})(\\w{4})(\\w{4})(\\w{12})",                            
                            "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5"); 
                    var val = /* Get val */

                    String response = gson.toJson(val);
                    outToClient.write(response);
                   outToClient.newLine();
                   outToClient.flush();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    outToClient.write(response);
                    outToClient.newLine();
                    outToClient.flush();
                }
            }

            connectionSocket.close();
        }
```

A little more explanation: *JAVA CODE DOESN'T GET HIT UNTIL THIS LINE IS COMPLETED* means that the socket appears to not be sending until *using (Socket sock = outputClient.Client)* is no longer being used.

Comment: What does this mean: "JAVA CODE DOESN'T GET HIT UNTIL THIS LINE IS COMPLETED" ? How could your C# program receive any data, if no Java code has executed at that point? And why does your question seem to otherwise indicate that the C# receive does _not_ complete? This question needs a lot of cleaning up, so that it makes some sense. As far as the C# code posted, the one major error you've made is to not check the byte count for the receive. More to the point, if you're using TcpClient (as it appears you are), why not get the NetworkStream from it and wrap in a StreamReader, as in the Java code?

Comment: I made a quick edit to explain it further.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help. Unless you set the socket to non-blocking, you can't get to the closing brace of the `using` block until some data has been received, which can't happen until some data has been sent. It's not possible that the Java side doesn't send until reaching the closing block of the `using` statement.

Comment: That's how it's been--if I remove `sock.Receive (response);` it sends it fine, if not it just hangs.

Comment: So when the `sock.Receive(response)` is there, what data is received?

Comment: Nothing, it just hangs there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64197/discussion-between-destiny-dawn-and-peter-duniho).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by replacing the C# code with:

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient (/IP ADDRESS/, /PORT/))
        using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream ())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (stream))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter (stream)) {
            writer.AutoFlush = true;

            foreach (string lineToSend in linesToSend) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Sending to server: {0}", lineToSend);
                writer.WriteLine (lineToSend);
                string lineWeRead = reader.ReadLine ();
                Console.WriteLine ("Received from server: {0}", lineWeRead);
                Thread.Sleep (2000); // just for effect
            }
            Console.WriteLine ("Client is disconnecting from server");
        }
```